# Azure Devops - Get Org ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I'm building an extension where I'm going to need some uniquely identifiable information about an org across all the installations of the extension. Is there an available API I can use to identify an organization? Preferably an ID.

is SDK.getHost().id the org id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is unique GUID for the org. You could also get host URL, which is also uniquely identifiable information, check this link:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/28

Comment: I never asked about restricting access to an organization. I asked about how to get unique information about the org such as the org id. It appears that SDK.getHost() will return an id that appears to be the org id which should work for me.

Comment: The id is unique GUID for the org. You could also get host URL, which is also uniquely identifiable information, check this link: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-extension-sdk/issues/28

Comment: So to clarify the answer please, so it means that Organization ID is basically the TenantID in its unique GUID format. Tenant ID can also be in the hot URL format but here in this context we are concerned with the GUID value.